# Resign keyboard on 'Done' button of keyboard

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I want to resign keyboard on click of 'Done' button on keyboard. How can i do this? I have following code =>

```
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

I have this code for limiting number of characters in textview =>

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

   if(range.length > text.length)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    else if([[textView text] length]  >= MAX_LENGTH_TEXTVIEW && range.length == 0)
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

How can i resign keyboard on clicking "Done" button of keyboard? If i click on Done , it's not resigning instead it is going to next line (i.e \n ). Is there any delegate method for "Done" method or so? i am not getting method for "Done" from apple documentation. 
plz help me ....thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your delegate should implement [- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) method

Comment: its a UITextView, not a UITextField

Comment: Why is this accepted when the answer doesn't work for UITextView?

Answer (score 3):

May be you can add another piece of code to your function:

```
if([[textView text] isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution. But if user wants to write on next line then how can I handle this?

Comment: next line is @"\r" or @"\r\n" you can add this check too, but as far as i know if you turn on the check wrap text, it will automatically go to the next line in case the user reached the end of the textview rectangle